# how to access smart card from JavaPOS

Tags: java, classpath, smartcard, javapos

I'm new to JavaPOS, can anyone let me know how to access smart card from Javapos.

Here's my code:

```
SmartCardRW smartCard = new SmartCardRW();
try {
        smartCard.open("ACR122U");      
} catch (JposException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I'm getting

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xml/serialize/BaseMarkupSerializer

How to get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

By downloading/adding Apache Xerces to your classpath, of course.